# Getting 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: magento2, http-status-403

After installing magento 2 via command line i get 403 Forbidden error trying to run setup.

I changed file permissions like this:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; 

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Still have issues. I've checked online to see if 403 has anything to do with anything but file permissions and this is all i'm getting to.